# How do I know with Angular and $q.all which requests succeeded and which failed

Tags: jquery, angularjs, promise, deferred

I have a table where the user can select multiple rows and hit the delete button. I need my code to loop through the selected records and delete them.

I am calling `customerService.delete({id: id})` to delete each record, however I need to know which failed and which succeeded so that I can handle it appropriately.

I have tried using `$q.all` but I'm not sure how to know which rows failed and which succeedd:

```
var promises = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked', $('#customers')).each(function() {
    var nRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
    var id = aData[0];      
    promises[id] = customerService.delete({id: id}).$promise;
});
$q.all(promises).then(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);         
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

How do I know which of my delete operations failed and succeeded?

EDIT: I have tried the below but am getting undefined for the `id` and `status`.

```
      var promises = [];
      $('input:checkbox:checked', $('#customers')).each(function() {
          var nRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
          var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
          var id = aData[0];
          var promise = customerService.delete({id: id}).$promise;
          promise.then(function(){
              return {status: true, id: id}
          }).catch(function(){
              return {status: false, id: id}
          })    
          promises.push(promise); 
      });

      $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
         $.each(results, function(result) {
           console.log(result.id + ' ' + result.status);
         });
      });
```

`results` looks like :

[image: Results array]

Answer (score 1):

`$q.all` accept promise array. Currently here you are creating `index` based push on array, which would not do anything (it will work on JSON/Object). Ideally you should be pushing promise into an array by doing `promises.push` like I shown below.

```
promises.push(customerService.delete({id: id}).$promise);
```

Comment: Why is there a problem in adding the promise to the array by index? Why does it need to be pushed?

Answer (score 1):

When you return inside `catch()` of a promise it will also pass a resolved promise down the chain

```
$('input:checkbox:checked', $('#customers')).each(function() {
    var nRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
    var id = aData[0];
    var promise =   customerService.delete({id: id}).$promise;
    promise.then(function(){
        return {status: true, id: id}
    }).catch(function(){
        return {status: false, id: id}
    })    
    promises.push(promise); 
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
   var failedDeletes = results.filter(function(item){
       return !item.status;
   });
});
```

Comment: return from `catch` to fulfil promise good point +1, great :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See my update. I am not seeing `status` and `id` reurned.

Comment: so what does `results` look like?

Comment: See my edit. It is an array (as expected)- I have shown the first key of the array. I don't see the `status` or `id` on the returned object.

Comment: So I changed the `.then` to simply show an alert once it runs, and it is only running if the delete operation was successful. I changed my backend code to throw a 404 and when it does that, the alert that I put inside of the `.then` function on `$`.all` doesn't get fired.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that $q.all only gives the first rejected value. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting
>   promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

You can see this happening in the below example where 'test3' is not returned even though it is rejected as well.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController($q) {
    var vm = this;
    var passedResults = [];
    var rejectedResults = [];

    function pushPassedResults(result) {
      passedResults.push(result);
    }

    function pushRejectedResults(result) {
      rejectedResults.push(result);
    }
    $q.all($q.reject('test1'), $q.reject('test3'),
        $q.when('test2'))
      .then(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);         
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
  ExampleController.$inject = ['$q'];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
</body>

</html>
```

To get the result we need to get it before $q.all has finished resolving the promises. Example below:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController($q) {
    var vm = this;
    var passedResults = [];
    var rejectedResults = [];

    function pushPassedResults(result) {
      passedResults.push(result);
    }

    function pushRejectedResults(result) {
      rejectedResults.push(result);
    }
    $q.all($q.reject('test1').then(pushPassedResults).catch(pushRejectedResults), 
           $q.reject('test3').then(pushPassedResults).catch(pushRejectedResults),
        $q.when('test2').then(pushPassedResults).catch(pushRejectedResults))
      .finally(function() {
        console.log("Passed results:" + passedResults);
        console.log("Rejected results:" + rejectedResults);
      });
  }
  ExampleController.$inject = ['$q'];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
</body>

</html>
```